# How to show $A_1 \approx A_2 \iff \mathrm{card}(A_1)=\mathrm{card}(A_2)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

For any set $A_1$ and $A_2$, let us define the relation $\approx$
if there exists a bijection between $A_1$ and $A_2$.
Then I want to show that $A_1 \approx A_2 \iff \mathrm{card}(A_1)=\mathrm{card}(A_2)$

where $\mathrm{card}$ means cardinal number.
I can use the fact : $A \preceq B$ and $B\preceq A \rightarrow A\approx B$ 
where $\preceq $ means there exists an one-to-one fucntion from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: How do you define $\mathrm{card}(A_1)=\mathrm{card}(A_2)$ ?

Comment: I suppose that the cardinal number is some particular ordinal?

Comment: By the definition of cardinal number, sure.

Comment: You haven't given us the definition of a cardinal number, though. (I assumed it is the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that $A\approx\alpha$.)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to define it...

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** It suffices to show that $\operatorname{card}(\alpha)=\alpha$ whenever $\alpha$ is a cardinal; and that $\approx$ is an equivalence relation.